# Django model query behaving strangly

Tags: django, django-models

This is really weird, this query

```
originator = User.objects.get(Q(emailaddress__email__exact=fromfield) | Q(phonenumber__exact=fromfield))
```

returns two objects, when I do query separately then I get only one object. I can't see why is this happening :(

```
    >>> originator = User.objects.get(emailaddress__email__exact=fromfield)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/site/gruppe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/site/gruppe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 401, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, kwargs))
DoesNotExist: GruppUser matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'emailaddress__email__exact': 9135261967L}
>>> originator = User.objects.get(phonenumber__exact=fromfield)
>>> originator
<GruppUser: jorge>
>>> originator = User.objects.get(Q(emailaddress__email__exact=fromfield) | Q(phonenumber__exact=fromfield))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/site/gruppe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 143, in get
    return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/site/gruppe/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 405, in get
    (self.model._meta.object_name, num, kwargs))
MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one GruppUser -- it returned 2! Lookup parameters were {}
```

And this is the queryset sql in raw:

```
(u'SELECT "gruppu_gruppuser"."password", "gruppu_gruppuser"."last_login", "gruppu_gruppuser"."is_superuser", "gruppu_gruppuser"."id", "gruppu_gruppuser"."username", "gruppu_gruppuser"."first_name", "gruppu_gruppuser"."last_name", "gruppu_gruppuser"."email", "gruppu_gruppuser"."is_staff", "gruppu_gruppuser"."is_active", "gruppu_gruppuser"."date_joined", "gruppu_gruppuser"."phonenumber", "gruppu_gruppuser"."mmsemail", "gruppu_gruppuser"."smsemail", "gruppu_gruppuser"."verified", "gruppu_gruppuser"."realname", "gruppu_gruppuser"."location", "gruppu_gruppuser"."website", "gruppu_gruppuser"."bio", "gruppu_gruppuser"."synctoFB" FROM "gruppu_gruppuser" LEFT OUTER JOIN "account_emailaddress" ON ("gruppu_gruppuser"."id" = "account_emailaddress"."user_id") WHERE ("account_emailaddress"."email" = %s  OR "gruppu_gruppuser"."phonenumber" = %s )', (u'9135261967', u'9135261967'))
```

And it selects the same user:

```
>>> queryset.all()
[<GruppUser: jorge>, <GruppUser: jorge>]
```

The SQL really select two, this is black magic to me :( :

```
                                   password                                    |          last_login           | is_superuser | id | username | first_name | last_name |      email       | is_staff | is_active |      date_joined       | phonenumber |         mmsemail         |              smsemail              | verified | realname | location | website | bio | synctoFB 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------+--------------+----+----------+------------+-----------+------------------+----------+-----------+------------------------+-------------+--------------------------+------------------------------------+----------+----------+----------+---------+-----+----------
 xxxx | 2014-02-09 08:49:06.225694+04 | f            |  2 | jorge    | Jorge      | Sanchez   | x@x.c| f        | t         | 2013-10-08 14:53:16+04 | 9135261967  | 9135261967@xx | 9135261967@xx | t        |          | Prague   |         |     | t
 xxxx| 2014-02-09 08:49:06.225694+04 | f            |  2 | jorge    | Jorge      | Sanchez   | x@x.c | f        | t         | 2013-10-08 14:53:16+04 | 9135261967  | 9135261967@xx | 9135261967@xx | t        |          | Prague   |         |     | t
(2 rows)
```

Comment: please chk the raw sql of your query. You print the queryset's query attribute.

'>>> queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
>>> print queryset.query
SELECT "myapp_mymodel"."id", ... FROM "myapp_mymodel", may be you get your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding .distinct() to the end of your query. As described in the documentation .all() does not eliminate duplicate rows but .distinct() will.

Here's the relevant documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct